# My If Statement is not functioning in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have assigned my selected option to a variable. However, when I use my if statement to compare the variable and a string, the if statement executes the code regardless of if the variable is equal to my string.

I have tried rewriting the code and doing some research on javascript if statements but, to my knowledge, I am unaware of any errors in my code.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#main_dropdown").change(function(){
        let selectedMajor = $(this).children("option:selected").val();              
        if (selectedMajor = 'arts') {
            alert("Your selected major is: " + selectedMajor);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: There's a difference between `=` and `==` (and `===`)

Comment: `=` is assignment, use `==` or `===` for equality check

Comment: `if (selectedMajor = 'arts') {` hmm that doesnt seem like comparison .. you are assigning a value .. you need `==` or `===` for comparison

Comment: The if statement works greate, it's just your condition, which is always passed.

Answer (score 4):

You are attempting to compare them using `=` which will actually assign 'arts' to the `selectedMajor` variable. Use `==` instead which will compare them.

If you need to make sure the types are the same as well, use `===`.

Comment: 3 upvotes on a simple answer like that. Why life is so hard on me ? :D

Comment: @NelsonTeixeira I'm asking the exact opposite question. :D

Answer (score 2):

In javascript `=` is used to assign a value to a variable, `==` is actually the eqaulity check operator.

Also use `trim()` function to check the compared value doesn't contain any leading/trailing space.

Try changing,

```
if (selectedMajor = 'arts') {
```

as,

```
if (selectedMajor.trim() == 'arts') {
```

Hope this helps!.

Comment: Feel free to mark my post as "answered" if it has helped you. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Your if statement is using the assignment =. You want to compare with the ==.

Answer (score 0):

`selectedMajor = 'arts'` is an [Assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Assignment_Operators#Assignment_2) which will always return the value on left hand side.

> Simple assignment operator is used to assign a value to a variable. The assignment operation evaluates to the assigned value

```js
let x = 3;
console.log(x = 3)
```

If you want to compare the value you should Abstract Equality `==` or Strict Equality `===`

```js
let x = 3;
console.log(x === 3)
```